# How to use JavaScript variable value as Object selector

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have a JavaScript variable:

```
var field = "Name";
```

Now I have an Object:

```
var obj = {Name: Bhaskor,Surname: Sarmah};
```

Now I need to select the `Name` field of obj using my field variable value:

```
var name = obj.(field);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) to get a property using a variable

```
var name = obj[field];
```

Comment: Is there any way to use the field inside a variable name like var x+[field]+count = 0;

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to replace your brackets:

```
var name = obj[field];
```